# 403 Forbidden message when trying to use Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

this has been mentioned here before and I tried passing through a fake user perimeter, but to no avail. Can you please help?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
})

page = requests.get('https://ingatlan.com/lista/elado+lakas')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
```

The error message is the following:

```
$ python hello.py
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   403 Forbidden
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <center>
   <h1>
    403 Forbidden
   </h1>
  </center>
  <hr/>
  <center>
   nginx
  </center>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its show response

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers={
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
}
def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        r = req.get(url).text

        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
        print(soup.prettify())

url = 'https://ingatlan.com/lista/elado+lakas'
main(url)
```